# php if elseif statement problem

Tags: php, http-post, if-statement

I have a very simple php program that I am working on for my computer science class but I am having a little trouble with it.

```
<?php
$numOfCards = '50'; //$_POST['numOfCards'];
$totalCost = 0.00;

if (numOfCards == '20')
{
$totalCost = $numOfCards*3.00;
}
else if (numOfCards == '50')
{
$totalCost = $numOfCards*2.50;
}
else
{
$totalCost = $numOfCards*2.00;
}

echo "<p>TOTAL COST FOR ".$numOfCards." CARDS: $".$totalCost."</p>";
?>
```

As you can see, I was originally getting my $numOfCards value from post data but have set it to 50 to prove a point. The issue is that this code as it is should go to the else if statement but instead it is going to the else statement. This results in totalCosts equalling $100 instead of $125.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have a `$` missing in `numOfCards` twice.

To easier find these problems enable error reporting and warnings on top of your script:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Then you will see two messages explaining that instead of comparing against a variable (as you wanted to) you compared against the string `"numOfCards"`.

Comment: Curious: What's the logic behind CW?

Comment: @mellamokb I don't like that pointing out  a missing `$` gains so much reputation. I'm trying this out for questions that are either about  a totally trivial manual link (background [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)) or a small typo

Comment: Thanks for all of the advice. I'm used to C# where simple errors like this would come up at compile time. I guess I'll have to pay more attention with php :(

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `$numOfCards` instead of just `numOfCards`.

Additionally you should **indent** your code blocks, preferably with 4-spaces per level:

```
if ($numOfCards == '20') {
    $totalCost = $numOfCards*3.00;
}
else if ($numOfCards == '50') {
    $totalCost = $numOfCards*2.50;
}
else {
    $totalCost = $numOfCards*2.00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `$` in the variable names.

```
if (**$**numOfCards == '20')
```

http://ideone.com/Y89nu

Answer (score -1):

Yes you missed a $ sign

The code should be

```
$numOfCards = '50'; 
//$_POST['numOfCards']; 
$totalCost = 0.00;  

if ($numOfCards  == '20') 
{     
  $totalCost = $numOfCards*3.00;     
} 
else if ($numOfCards  == '50') 
{     
  $totalCost = $numOfCards*2.50;     
} 
else 
{     
  $totalCost = $numOfCards*2.00;     
}  

echo "<p>TOTAL COST FOR ".$numOfCards." CARDS: $".$totalCost."</p>";
```